# Wordpress \r\n in Content

Tags: wordpress

I've imported a Wordpress database into another server and I'm getting `\r\n` in all the posts and pages content.

I've tried re-importing the `wp_posts` table, and exporting/importing as *MYSQL40*

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting newlines, or the actual characters `\r\n` ? If it's the former, this can sometimes happen when editing a text file both on Windows and another OS, or when transferring with a FTP client in ASCII mode between mixed OS's. In that case you can search/replace `\r\n` to `\n` by regex in the affected file.

Comment: You imported how? From what type of database? How did you export the data? You should be more specific on your actions for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @mch, I got it working with that info